# Setting GhostScript -sFONTMAP argument to control parameters

Tags: ghostscript

I am using GhostPCl version 9.53 in order to convert PCL files to PDF. In the course of my testing, I’ve encountered challenges related to fontmap usage. The converted PDF file has slight changes related to the fonts. My target is to change the fonts that are automatically set by GhostScript.
I invoke ghostPCL through command prompt with parameters like for example:

gpcl6win64.exe -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dSAFER -sFONTMAP=custom_fontmap.gs -sOutputFile=local.pdf local.pcl

May I ask if the current version of GhostPCL supports fontmap functionality ? My second question would be if there is any possible way or a specific version of GhostPCL that incorporates fontmap support ? If not, are there any considerations for future releases to include that feature ? Any insights or guidance you can provide on this matter would be highly appreciated.

GhostScript has very own Fontmap.gs in it's directory. I want to add fonts, so should I add it to this fontmap or use custom one ?

In my custom fontmap I want to add font that is external font file:

/sv0p0s0b0t D:/temp/test_gs_fonts/ttf/sv0p0s0b0t.ttf

And call it from Command Prompt like this, where customfontmap.gs is in the same directory as the gpcl6win64.exe :

gpcl6win64.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sFontmap=customfontmap.gs -sOutputFile=owl.pdf owl.pcl

When I execute this script and open the file through notepad++ and hex editor neo in order to read the file scirpt,
fontmap parameters is "-sFontmap=? ". Is it possible to set the fontmap like that ?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I edited the question to be specific.